# Unable to import Excel Add in in Excel Online

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, excel-addins

Hi I have taken a sample github project https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-in-JS-QuarterlySalesReport/blob/master/Readme.md ,
and after making a few changes in manifest was able to successfully  import the add in in my desktop excel app **Version 1611 Build 7571.2006** ( the add-in web app  was running on my local box itself)

Now i am trying to  upload this add on online excel, while my web app runs on my local box  but I am getting  this error on online excel

[image]

Here is the manifest i upload to online excel (this manifest file is same as the manifest which works on excel desktop  except that i replaced the  ip address from 127.0.0.1 to my public ip )

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
      <Id>adc22a5f-62c5-472e-b258-2ae44be6fccf</Id>
      <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
      <ProviderName>ML LABS</ProviderName>
      <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
      <DisplayName DefaultValue="ML LABSII" />
      <Description DefaultValue="ML LABSII"/>
     <Hosts>
           <Host Name="Workbook" />
     </Hosts>
      <DefaultSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="http://172.22.136.62:3000/" />
      </DefaultSettings>
      <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
    </OfficeApp>
```

I have tried and the web app loads from other machine browsers with no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible issue is that you have an **http** URL, whereas it needs to be **https** (esp. for Office Online).

Comment: yes making it to Https   loaded it  correctly , but I am another  doubt  how can can  reload  excel plugin in online excel , in desktop app there is a "reload"  button  how  does one  "reload" or "delete"  add in added to a  online excel  file  ??